# Restructure array of objects then grouping objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

So I have found a solution, but I am still learning and feel like my solution is too long. It does not use all of ES6 and could be better. I would love any feedback and/or suggestions.

The data looks like this:

```
const formattedWorkbook = 
     [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "mainHeaderEnglish": "Pearls of Wisdom",
            "categoryCode": 3,
        },
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "mainHeaderEnglish": "VENuS Satellite",
            "categoryCode": 2,
        },
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "mainHeaderEnglish": "Hope for millions",
            "categoryCode": 1,
        },
        {
            "year": 2012,
            "mainHeaderEnglish": "green electricity Pioneer",
            "categoryCode": 2
        }
    ]
```

The data needs to look like this:

```
const formattedWorkbook = 
     [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "value: [
               {"mainHeaderEnglish": "Pearls of Wisdom", "categoryCode": 3,}
             ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "value":[
              {"mainHeaderEnglish": "VENuS Satellite", "categoryCode": 2},
              {"mainHeaderEnglish": "Hope for millions", "categoryCode": 1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2012,
            "value": [
              {"mainHeaderEnglish": "green electricity Pioneer", "categoryCode": 2}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

This is my solution that works, but I think it could be a lot better:

```
let transformedWorkbook = formattedWorkbook.map(function (obj) {
    const result = {
        year: obj.year,
        value: []
    }

    for (let year in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(year) && year !== "year") {
            result.value.push({ [year]: obj[year] });
        }
    }

    result.value = [Object.assign({}, ...result.value)]
    return result;
});

const newWorkbook = new Map(transformedWorkbook.map(({ year, value }) => [year, { year, value: [] }]));

for (let { year, value } of transformedWorkbook) {
    newWorkbook.get(year).value.push(...[value].flat())
};

console.log([...newWorkbook.values()]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could still use the `map` but take `year` out of the object and map new object with the grouped result.

In pieces:

- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) takes an iterable, like an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) is implemented *and* a mapping function and returns an array.
- To get a grouped dataset, you could take [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which uses an accumulator, like an instance of `Map` and iterates the given array of objects.

  To get a property from the object and keeping the rest,

  ```
  { year, ...o }
  ```

  you could take a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for `year` and get the [rest if object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring). Now you have two parts, the wanted property for grouping and the rest for collecting as value.

  [`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) takes a value from the instance and [`Map#set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) stores the value.

  In case of not getting an array as value, you need to use a default value

  ```
  m.get(year) || []
  ```

  with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), which returns the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, like an array, but not `undefined`.

  This value is [spreaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into a new array along with the actual object

  ```
  [...m.get(year) || [], o]
  ```

  as new value for the `Map`.
- Finally the mapping function of `Array.from`

  ```
  ([year, value]) => ({ year, value })
  ```

  takes a destructuring of key and value of the given `Map` and generates a new object with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) as new result.

```js
const formattedWorkbook = [{ year: 2016, mainHeaderEnglish: "Pearls of Wisdom", categoryCode: 3 }, { year: 2017, mainHeaderEnglish: "VENuS Satellite", categoryCode: 2 }, { year: 2017, mainHeaderEnglish: "Hope for millions", categoryCode: 1 }, { year: 2012, mainHeaderEnglish: "green electricity Pioneer", categoryCode: 2 }],
    result = Array.from(
        formattedWorkbook.reduce((m, { year, ...o }) =>
            m.set(year, [...m.get(year) || [], o]), new Map),
        ([year, value]) => ({ year, value })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: really short and elegant, but very much over my head

Comment: You are fantastic, thank you for taking the time to write that out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group your array data based on `year`:

```js
const formattedWorkbook = 
     [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "mainHeaderEnglish": "Pearls of Wisdom",
            "categoryCode": 3,
        },
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "mainHeaderEnglish": "VENuS Satellite",
            "categoryCode": 2,
        },
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "mainHeaderEnglish": "Hope for millions",
            "categoryCode": 1,
        },
        {
            "year": 2012,
            "mainHeaderEnglish": "green electricity Pioneer",
            "categoryCode": 2
        }
    ]
    
let result = formattedWorkbook.reduce((acc,cur) => {
    let { year, ...rest } = cur;
    let ex = acc.find(x => x.year === year);
    if(!ex){
       ex = { year, value: [] };
       acc.push(ex);
    }
    ex.value.push(rest);
    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for that:

```
_.map(formattedWorkbook, el => {
  return {
    year: el.year,
      value: {
        mainHeaderEnglish: el.mainHeaderEnglish,
        categoryCode: el.categoryCode
      }
  }
});
```

If you prefer native javascript functions:

```
formattedWorkbook.map(el => {
  return {
    year: el.year,
      value: {
        mainHeaderEnglish: el.mainHeaderEnglish,
        categoryCode: el.categoryCode
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not the output I asked for, the years need to be grouped and values with the same year should be put in a value array inside the object